# Creating a Virtual Environment in terminal for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

Basically I'm trying to create a virtual environment in terminal with a book. So I typed in terminal like this by first creating a directory called learning_log.

```
$ mkdir learning_log
$ cd learning_log/
learning_log$ python3 -m venv ll_env
learning_log$
```

And now I'm trying to install virtualenv and create virtual environment but it shows that there is no such command "virtualenv ll_env".

```
learning_log$ pip3 install --user virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages
learning_log$ virtualenv ll_env
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

While the book shows that

```
learning_log$ virtualenv ll_env
New python executable in ll_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
learning_log$
```

Why does my terminal shows that there's no such command for virtuaenv rather than according to what the books shows?

Comment: Your `python` command is equivalent to the `virtualenv` wrapper - all you need to do now is `activate` it by doing e.g. `source ll_env/bin/activate` and then running `pip` etc for whatever other packages you need.

Comment: I don't really quite understand. Basically in the situation of not typing "virtual ll_env: and then skipping to typing source ""ll_eng/bin/activate"", it still shows that "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" when typing "pip3 install Django".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure you typed the full command that was mentioned, including the source part?

```
source ll_env/bin/activate
```

If the virtual environment is active you will see it beside the path, in your case you will see (ll_env). With the virtual environment active it will know to use pip3 so to install Django you will run

```
pip install django
```

Comment: Basically after activated "source ll_env/bin/activate and then typing "pip3 install Django", it again shows that "The: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".

Comment: Do you get the same error when you type `pip install django` instead of `pip3 install django`? With the virtual environment active you don't need to type the 3 in pip3

Comment: Ooops.. Yes. it still shows "The: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" even if I typed "pip install Django".

Comment: With the virtual environment active, what do you get when you type `python --version`?

Comment: It shows "Python 3.6.4" after typing "python --version" with the virtual environment active.

Comment: Any chance you have any spaces in the path to your directory? That can cause issues. Something like `my directory/learning_log/` instead of `my_directory/learning_log/`

Comment: Ah, does "leaning_log" directory" have to be saved on strictly some certain path rather than on personalised directory(which is my personal directory where I do python projects)?

Comment: OK, that looks like it is probably your issue. "The Universe" has a space in it as does "Practice PCC". If you change "The Universe" to "The_Universe" and "Practice PCC" to "Practice_PCC" it will probably fix your issue.

Comment: Hmm, It still shows that "The: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" even if I corrected those two paths(The_Universe and Practice_PCC).

Comment: Looks like the virtual environment is still trying to use the old path. What happens if you delete the virtual environment and recreate it? Deactivate it first by typing `deactivate`. Then remove the virtual environment `rm -r ll_env`. Then create it again `python3 -m venv ll_env`